# Is "radio DJ" a collocation?

Tags: collocations

I am asked in the English exam I've recently taken online to make a collocation with the given word. Like this sample: *Ice*-...*cream*
but with the word *radio*:

> Radio - a)pm  b)mp  c)DJ

I chose the c option because I was imagining the occupation-a DJ person, but I googled it later but with no results, it wasn't in most dictionaries.

Comment: The top result from Googling **define radio dj** is [this definition.](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00Ir0Ca6iUL60J7PNckV8yvXcPwNg%3A1585501325381&ei=jdSAXqvrFpaf1fAPgp2DmAk&q=define+radio+dj&oq=define+radio+dj&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQFhAeOgQIABBHUJPvAliv_gJg9oMDaABwA3gAgAH3AYgBsgOSAQUwLjEuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjr5ajalMDoAhWWTxUIHYLOAJMQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) from thefreedictionary. What else do you need to know?

Comment: right Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Englishvibes Well, *radio DJ* is a *collocation*, and most dictionaries do not have those. However, dictionaries aimed at learners, and special, collocation, dictionaries often contain this information. However, I was unable to find it in a [collocation dictionary](http://freecollocation.com/), or in a [learner's dictionary](https://ldoceonline.com/). In this case I believe you should simply know the meaning of the three options to decide which one's best. *PM* normally stands for "Prime Minister" or "post meridiem", and *MP* means "Member of Parliament". *DJ* is the only one that fits.

Comment: Thank you so much